# Override inner cols with inner rows Smarty columns

Tags: sorting, foreach, smarty, rows

I have 3 columns inside a table and my information is being displayed correctly. However, the information is being displayed horizontally in the smarty template.

1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9

How can I display it vertically instead?

Like this:
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9

What I need is a solution, Something similar to this:
    {html_table inner=rows cols=3 loop=$array}

```
{* Categories *}
{if !empty($categs)}
{if !empty($category.ID)}
<h3>{l}Books{/l}</h3>
{/if}
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
{foreach from=$categs item=cat name=categs}
{if ($smarty.foreach.categs.iteration mod $cats_per_col eq 1 and $cats_per_col gt 1) or    $smarty.foreach.categs.first}<td>{/if}
<h2 {if !empty($category.ID)}class="blocktext"{/if}><a href="{if !empty($cat.URL)}    {$cat.URL}{else}{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/{$cat.CACHE_URL|escape}{/if}" {if $cat.NEW_WINDOW eq 1}target="blank"{/if}  title="{$cat.TITLE|escape}" class="catHomeMain">{$cat.TITLE|escape} </a>{if $smarty.const.CATS_COUNT}{if !empty($cat.URL)}{else} <span class="catHomeCount">({$cat.COUNT})</span>{/if}{/if}</h2>
{* Display subcategories *}
{if !empty($cat.SUBCATS)}
{foreach from=$cat.SUBCATS item=scat name=scategs key=key}
{capture name="column"}{math equation="x % 3" x=$key}{/capture}
{if $smarty.capture.column == "0"}
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td width="177px">
<ul class="navcontainer"><li>
    <a href="{if !empty($scat.URL)}{$scat.URL}{else}   {$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/{$scat.CACHE_URL|escape}{/if}" {if $scat.NEW_WINDOW eq 1}target="blank"{/if}  title="{$scat.TITLE|escape}" class="catHomeSub">{$scat.TITLE|escape}</a></li></ul>
            </td>
{elseif  $smarty.capture.column == "1"}
    <td width="177px">
<ul class="navcontainer"><li>
<a href="{if !empty($scat.URL)}{$scat.URL}{else}  {$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/{$scat.CACHE_URL|escape}{/if}" {if $scat.NEW_WINDOW eq 1}target="blank"{/if}  title="{$scat.TITLE|escape}" class="catHomeSub">{$scat.TITLE|escape}</a>
</li></ul>
    </td>
{elseif $smarty.capture.column == "2"}
    <td width="177px">
<ul class="navcontainer"><li>
<a href="{if !empty($scat.URL)}{$scat.URL}{else}  {$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/{$scat.CACHE_URL|escape}{/if}" {if $scat.NEW_WINDOW eq 1}target="blank"{/if}  title="{$scat.TITLE|escape}" class="catHomeSub">{$scat.TITLE|escape}</a>
</li></ul>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
{/if}
{/foreach}

{if $smarty.capture.column != 2}
<!-- Close the table! -->
</tr></table>
{/if}
{/if}
{if ($smarty.foreach.categs.iteration mod $cats_per_col eq 0 and $cats_per_col gt 1) or $smarty.foreach.categs.last}</td>{/if}
{/foreach}
</tr>
</table>
<div class="break" style="height:20px;"></div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

First I created an array in the PHP file:

```
$tpl->assign('old', array('item1','item3','item5','item2','item4','item6'));
```

Then in the .TPL file i rewrote the code like this:

```
{if $cat.TITLE == "Old Books"}

<table> 

<tr> 

{section name=nr loop=$old} 

<td style="width:177px;">

<ul class="navcontainer"><li>

<a href="{$smarty.const.DOC_ROOT}/{$old[nr]}/" title="{$old[nr]|replace:'_':' '|escape}" class="catHomeSub">{$old[nr]|replace:'_':' '|escape}</a></li></ul></td> 

{if $smarty.section.nr.iteration % 3 == 0} 

</tr> 

<tr> 

{/if} 

{/section} 

</tr> 

</table>
```

This will output the data in 3 columns "sorted" vertically.

item1 item3 item5
item2 item4 item6